# How do I filter within variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this

```
N = 10
A <- rnorm(N)
B <- rnorm(N) 
Year <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016)
CityID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df<- data.frame(CityID, A, B, Year)
```

How do I make a scatter plot that has:

- on the x-axis: variable `A` but only for `year == 2012`
- on the y-axis: variable `B` but only `year == 2015`

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, You can't, well, actually you can, but your plot would be empty as you don't have points that are at the same time `year == 2012` and `year == 2015`.

Comment: You shouldn't use ggplot for data manipulation. If you want to transform your data before plotting, consider using `dplyr`, something like `dplyr::reframe(df, x=A[Year==2012], y=B[Year==2015])` maybe? It's unclear how you want to match up the 2012 and 2015 values for plotting.

Comment: Hi, I basically want the 2012 values on the x-axis and want to see how it affects the 2015 value. Say, I have data from many cities from many years (2008-2020) and want to show areas that had high levels of pollution in 2012 have high levels of asthma in 2015

Comment: @anrisakaki96 What's confusing is that there is no "city" column in your example. This makes it hard to match up the data.

Comment: To correspond 2012 and 2015 values you should have and ID (same observation ID in 2012 and 2015)

Comment: Maybe you have observations of both asthma and pollution for each city each year. Then you might do something you asked for.

Comment: Added CityID :)

Comment: not quite yet ID 1 is seen 2 times in 2012 and ID 4 is seen 2 times in 2015

Comment: For each city and year you seem to have two values of A and two values of B. How do you want to handle the multiple values? Average them? Assume they are ordered the same way and plot two points?

Comment: Il suggest somthing like 2 lines plot one line for pollution values by years ans second line for asthma value by years facetting by city or coloring by city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first make some data with a yearly measurement for pollution and asthma for each city ID:

```r
library(tidyverse)

N = 25
asthma <- runif(N)
pollution <- runif(N) 
Year <- rep(2012:2016, each = 5)
Cities <- rep(c('A','B','C','D','E'), times = 5)
df<- data.frame(Cities, asthma, pollution, Year)

head(df, 10)
#>    Cities     asthma  pollution Year
#> 1       A 0.39888372 0.29314668 2012
#> 2       B 0.01967627 0.71391652 2012
#> 3       C 0.44811480 0.49369666 2012
#> 4       D 0.04756653 0.68682790 2012
#> 5       E 0.06945347 0.15169561 2012
#> 6       A 0.04145539 0.46718386 2013
#> 7       B 0.44021672 0.26933620 2013
#> 8       C 0.62954974 0.02934014 2013
#> 9       D 0.77613099 0.42838978 2013
#> 10      E 0.95354053 0.07474578 2013
```

Now you can coloring points by year and create a facet for each city

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(asthma, pollution, color = factor(Year))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Cities)
```

[image]

It may be worth considering other ways of viewing your data. Bars or columns might make it easier for you to note a year with high pollution, and look to a subsequent year with high asthma.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(asthma, pollution)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(Year), value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  facet_wrap(~ Cities)
```

[image]

Or as @Wael suggests in a comment:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(asthma, pollution)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(Year), value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ Cities)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you can make a new data.frame where you keep the values of A for 2012, and values of B for 2015. And then plot using ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
    df2 <- data.frame(A = df[df$Year == 2012,"A"], B =df[df$Year == 2015,"B"])

ggplot2::ggplot(df2) +
    geom_point(aes(A,B))
```

Comment: if I misunderstood the question please let me know and I can update my answer!